# How can we wrap words in a lable in .net maui 7

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

Here is the .Net Maui  code

```
  <Label x:Name="LblName" FontSize="Default" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" TextColor="White" ></Label>
```

I'm trying to wrap the text but so far, nothing seems to be working. I've used all of the "LineBreakMode(s)" in conjunction with the "MaxLines".

The data in label is coming from the code behind file using the "LblName".

I've used all of the "LineBreakMode(s)" in conjunction with the "MaxLines".

Comment: This is not enough code and information to [reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the issue. What string do you want to display? What does it look like at the moment and what should it look like?

Comment: Code inside xaml:
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto" ColumnDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto">
<Label Grid.Row="0" x:Name="LblName" FontSize="Medium"/>
</Grid>

Data is coming from code behind file from the constructor like this:
public PageName(Model modelItem){
   InitializeComponent();
   modelItem.Text = modelItem.Name;
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I can reproduce this issue. Only one line can be shown.

In fact it's a known issue on Github: [Label doesn't render correctly when in a Grid with column definitions #10494](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10494). And [hartez comments](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10494#issuecomment-1269199076) gave compelling explanation that it is caused because the ColumnDefinitions is set to Auto which makes a infinite width. This issue is still unsolved now. You could follow this thread.

For workaround, you could set the ColumnDefinitions to * or give a specific value.

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a Button instead. They autowrap and with a transparent background and Disable, they are basically a Label to look at.

```
<Button IsEnabled="False" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
```